# Best structure to store a graph?

Tags: performance-tuning, graphs-and-networks, storage

I have a weighted, undirected graph with weighted edges, that could be represented in mathematica by the following code for $N=3$

```
    Graph[{Labeled[1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, "0.21+\[ImaginaryI]"], 
  Labeled[2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, "2"], 
  Labeled[3 \[UndirectedEdge] 1, "1"]}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

What is the best way to store such graphs when $N\sim 10^6$ with regard to memory usage, retrieval of edge/vertices weights speed, and value replacement speed ?

I know about matrices and sparse matrices, and associations. But these structures generally include redundant information or useless ones (lots of 0 for example...). Is there anything more efficient ? Including in other languages if you happen to know anything abouth other languages !

Comment: Store vertex and edge data (such as weights) in a packed array. And store the graph combinatorics  in the form of the adjacency matrix in a sparse array. The point of sparse arrays is that the zeros are _not_ stored explicitly.

Comment: It's not really clear to me what the question is. What do you want to achieve? Store it in a compact format in a file? Store it in a compact way in memory? Store it in memory in such a way that it can be manipulated efficiently? If so, _how_ do you plan to manipulate it?

Comment: Basically, I have an algorithm that simulates few atom interactions on a grid, and I am building a Hamiltonian which effectively is nothing but a big matrix or a graph linking states. The number of states in the Hilbert space I am considering is kind of big, and  I am working on optimizing my code, the suggestion by Henrik regarding PackedArrays, was nice, and I am now using them.  When pushing it to the limits, my programm runs out of memory, I think RAM, (but I am not an expert), and so I was looking for ways to store the same data (the hamiltonian elements), in the most compact way...

Comment: ...while still being able to retrieve elements rapidly because to build adjacent elements to a given element of the graph, I need to know what this element is, so I cannot use things like Compress for example. I was looking for suggestions much like Henrik provided, not like a ready to use code or anything. @Szabolcs

Comment: @yfs It seems your application relies on linear algebra, so _sparse_ matrices seem like a natural choice. You say, "But these structures generally include redundant information or useless ones (lots of 0 for example...)." This is not true for sparse matrices.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DumpSave`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DumpSave.html):

```
g = GridGraph[{1000, 1000}];

VertexCount[g]
```

> ```
> 1000000
> ```

```
ByteCount[g]
```

> ```
> 95969272
> ```

```
DumpSave["graph.mx", g];

FileByteCount["graph.mx"]
```

> ```
> 47968625
> ```

The caveat is when retrieving the graph, we need to reinitialize it too after importing the mx file. My guess is that mx files store the expression in `InputForm` and `Graph` is not a regular expression.

```
<<"graph.mx";

VertexCount[g]; // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.791, Null}
> ```

```
g = g;

VertexCount[g]; // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {4.3*10^-7, Null}
> ```